# Sending JSON with python

Tags: python, json

I have several questions that i would appreciate if they were answered but first 
a little background so you will know what I'm looking for here..
I have written a code in python that parses some information from a website and saves the content to a list. To simplify things i will show you the code i have right now.

```
import lxml.html
from lxml.etree import XPath


url = "http://gbgfotboll.se/information/?scr=table&ftid=51168"
date = '2014-09-27'
# use this in real mode: currentDate = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
list = []
rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table[3]/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))
time_xpath = XPath("td[1]/span/span//text()[2]")
team_xpath = XPath("td[2]/a/text()")

html = lxml.html.parse(url)

for row in rows_xpath(html):
    time = time_xpath(row)[0].strip()
    team = team_xpath(row)[0]
    list.append(time + " " + team)
```

I want to be able to send this list to my own iphone application. I have read different posts, forums you name it but i can't seem to find something to satisfy me.

**Questions**

1) The list i have should i convert it to a dictionary before i send it or do i just use normal json.dump()?

2) After making the content to JSON format how would i get this content to a web service so i can make requests from the iphone application to retrieve the information? Is this possible in python?

If I'm saying something wrong here I'm am very sorry I'm am new at this but now I'm tired of searching on the web after 3 days i need some direct answers. If i said anything wrong please just correct me and tell me the right way to do what i want to do.

Many Thanks!!

Comment: "I have several questions" usually means you should post several questions, not just one.

Comment: Also, "The list i have should i convert it to a dictionary before i send it": Well, that depends on information you haven't given us. What format do you want the iPhone app to see it in? If you want a JSON object (dict), convert it to a dictionary. If you want a JSON array (list), don't. Also, when you "convert it to a dictionary", what would the keys and values be? If you don't have an answer to that, you probably don't want a dictionary; if there's an obvious answer to that, you often do.

Comment: You can clearly see i got 2 questions and in the second one i have 2 questions so total of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 'sending' the output to your iPhone, how about fetching it from your app? If you run your code as a Flask app on a public accessible webserver, that should be easy. I guess the iOS SDK has a library that handles HTTP requests. A simplified example:

```
from flask import Flask
import lxml.html
import json
from lxml.etree import XPath

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    url = "http://gbgfotboll.se/information/?scr=table&ftid=51168"
    date = '2014-09-27'
    # use this in real mode: currentDate = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    list = []
    rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table[3]/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))
    time_xpath = XPath("td[1]/span/span//text()[2]")
    team_xpath = XPath("td[2]/a/text()")

    html = lxml.html.parse(url)

    for row in rows_xpath(html):
        time = time_xpath(row)[0].strip()
        team = team_xpath(row)[0]
        list.append(time + " " + team)

    return json.dump(list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

About your question if you should convert your list to a dict: that's not necessary.

By the way; instead of using lxml/xpath, you could also use BeautifulSoup to browse through a DOM. That's a bit easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: Yes that is what i was thinking of doing. My iphone application will make a GET request and when it does it will get the data that is stored in the list.

How would i get my information from python to an accessible web server? Would i need to do this manually? Because i want this to be something automatic?

Ok so regular json.dumps() is enough?. Do i need to dump the JSON content to a file?  @Bjorn

Comment: I have read that lxml/xpath is much faster than beautifulSoup but thanks anyway @Bjorn

Comment: I've updated my code with a simple (untested) example. But I guess this should get you started. You could run this app on a Heroku (like) service. Heroku has a tutorial which will help you deploy your first app: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python-o

Comment: Lxml/xpath is much faster that BS3, true. But BS4 uses Lxml as the internal parser. So you'll get the easy-to-read source without a large performance penalty.

Comment: Ok wonderful thank you so much. Just one last question to clarify things. With the code you provided me, how would my iphone application get the list content using Heroku. If you would just say like the steps it would go? Example first the request comes from the phone to ?.. and so on @Bjorn

Answer (score 0):

To add to [@Bjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189362/bjorn)'s answer, something that might not be clear: the Python code that you write doesn't need to put the JSON output somewhere else for the app to then retrieve; rather, the Python code *is* the web service, and every time your app makes an HTTP request to it, the code will run again, generating a new JSON list, and return that in the HTTP response.

So in order for this to work, you need to have a web server running somewhere, such as Heroku as Bjorn suggested (in the tutorial he linked, you would replace the contents of their `hello` function with your code). Once it's running, there will be some URL that you can make HTTP requests to. For your iPhone app to get the data, it can make a request to that URL, and the web server will run your Python code and return the JSON list to the app.

Also, it should be `json.dumps` rather than `json.dump` (the latter requires a file to write to, whereas the former just returns the JSON-encoded string).

Comment: Thats what i wanted to hear :D Now i can start doing things! I would need to write some code for it to handle the GET/POST requests right? @Avril

Comment: The `hello` method in @Bjorn's example is what would happen on a GET request.  The `@app.route` decorator is what tells flask that - the "/" means that the path you'd make the GET request to is the root path of the application (for example, if your webserver is `http://myserver.example.com/`, then making a request to that URL would return your JSON list), and it assumes the method is GET if you don't specify.  To make a function that handles POST requests, you could decorate it with `@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])`.

Comment: I got it up and running and i can see the list of strings in the simulator thank you so much :D. @Avril